# stuck on sliders with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am building a portfolio page of different work that has been done and im using two different jquery sliding techniques, one nested in amongst the other one.

The first slider works great but the second one doesnmt work that great for the first few and then doesnt work at all. If you take a look at this page- You can click the clients up and down the left side to slide the main divs, but when you click on the squares in below the images to slide in and out the content, either it doesnt work as smoothly as it should or it doesnt work right at all.

http://justni.com/wip/mdd/martin_duggan_portfolio.html

anyone wanna take a look at the code and tell  me what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This not a JQuery issue, you need to add proper styling for the slider

you must add these properties in your css file

```
.coda-slider
{   position: relative;
}
.coda-slider .panel-container
{   position: absolute;
}
.coda-slider .panel
{   float: left;
    width: 675px;
}
```